# Passing the latest state of an instance to another instance. Is there a better way?

Tags: python

I have 2 classes that are not linked by inheritance. Instance of Class A needs a method from instance of Class B to update itself. And the method of Class B needs the latest state of instance A in order to know what to compute.

In the minimum code below:

1. Instance of A has a variable x.
2. In order to update x, A's instance asks B's instance to update variable x
3. B's instance gets the latest copy of A's instance and processes the variable x

The problem is I am literally having to pass the complete instance of A via `b.processX(self)` method call.

Is inheritance the only way to achieve this? Is there no other way? Is there a more pythonic way than passing a full instance of A into B via (self)?

```
class A:

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.x = value

    def updateX(self,b):
        self.x = b.processX(self) # <-- IS THERE A BETTER WAY?
        return self.x

class B:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def processX(self,a):
        a.x += 5
        return a.x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(10)
    b = B()
    ret = a.updateX(b)
    print(ret)
```

EDIT: the reason I am asking this is in my actual code, A's instance can become very big with thousands of datapoints and I am concerned about performance if every call to B results in massive data structures being passed from one instance to the other

Comment: Does it not make sense to have an instance of `B` as an attribute of `A`, and have an instance of `A` as an attribute of `B`? Will the instances passed to each class change? Is your main concern just needing to supply each object each time?

Comment: And note that re: " if every call to B results in massive data structures being passed from one instance to the other". The size of the datastructure being passed shouldn't effect performance. The structures aren't copied when passed as arguments.

Comment: Given that `b.processX` updates its argument in-place, I don't see the problem.  You  are only passing a fixed-size *reference* to `A`, not a copy of the data.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, the main concern is having the pass the full instance of A into B every time I make the call as A is going to get very very big. I am not sure if there would be performance impacts to making this call at scale. A's instance will be constantly changing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Got it. That's helpful!

Comment: might also be worth considering if object orientation is the right approach; i.e. why not just have a function outside of both classes that just does `process_and_update(a, b)`.  doing it this way can make it clearer what's going on without having to untangle two otherwise inseparable methods